# I got error "Information not available, no symbols loaded for d3dcompiler_47.dll" from D3DCompile function

Tags: windows, window, directx, directx-11, direct3d

I got error "Information not available, no symbols loaded for d3dcompiler_47.dll" from D3DCompile function.
But dependency walker show d3dcompiler_47.dll is loaded and D3DCompile function is also loaded.
I can't find how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an error. It's a "warning" from the debugger that it can't find debugging symbols for that library. It will still run and work just fine.

Symbols for Microsoft binaries are available from *Microsoft Symbol Server*.

For using the symbol server from Visual Studio, see [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger).

See also [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/understanding-symbol-files-and-visual-studios-symbol-settings/).